# emulate ENTER in .txt

Tags: keyboard, command, ascii, device-emulation, enter

Can someone please help in adding a command for <kbd>enter</kbd> in a `.txt` file to emulate <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Example:
12345<kbd>enter</kbd>548793<kbd>enter</kbd>.....

where an entry will be a number followed by enter to next field where the next number will be inserted etc..  so it will look like this:

```
12345
548793
etc...
```

Comment: What language (or tool) do you want to use to accomplish this? If you need help on what tool to use, indicate the operating system that you are using.

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve, besides adding a newline after each number ?

Comment: Depending on which OS it uses, hitting enter will send a combination of the ASCII carriage return (hex 0x0D / dec 13) and line feed (hex 0x0A / dec 10).  Most likely just line feed, as only Windows tends to use both.

Comment: Question is extremely unclear. Clarify or delete.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between an enter and a return (-- old skool typewriter stuff - check Wikipedia on that).

One is a carriage return and one is a line feed; the ASCII codes for those are 10 and 13, I'd say test and find out which one (if not both) you'll need.

Normally (in like C++,C#,etc) you'd post \r\n --> 10 13

Comment: im importing a series of numbers which were captured by a scanner.  the numbers are separated by a comma.  I would like to insert a enter command in between the numbers so i can copy and paste from a notepad.txt into a spreadsheet in a column format.

Comment: Now that's more information then you've left in the original post; 
What programming language are you using to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just add newlines in the file?

```
12345
548793
etc...
```

Comment: I think he has a file where "ENTER" (case insensitive) should be replaced with a newline. The problem is what tool / language he hopes to use to substitute string literals for newlines.

Comment: im importing a series of numbers which were captured by a scanner. the numbers are separated by a comma. I would like to insert a enter command in between the numbers so i can copy and paste from a notepad.txt into a spreadsheet in a column format

Answer (score 0):

The script that is reading in your txt file should already recognize whichever [EOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character the text editor used.  Many scripting languages automatically understand the various EOLs when reading from a filehandle.  If yours doesn't, you may have to compose a regex that looks for the most common ones.